# Magento check if customer logged in multistore

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, login, customer-session, logout

I have Magento 1.9.2.4 CE installed in one of my client's site which is multistore site.

Now I have following code in header file for checking whether a customer is logged in or not using session model and showing appropriate login/logout links as per condition.

```
<?php
                foreach($_storeArr as $store):
                    $storeBaseUrl = Mage::app()->getStore($store['id'])->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
                    $helper = Mage::helper('customer');
                    $custSession = Mage::getModel('customer/session'); ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php if ($custSession->isLoggedIn()): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $storeBaseUrl.'customer/account/logout'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout ').$store['name']; ?></a>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $storeBaseUrl.'customer/account/login'; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login ').$store['name']; ?></a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

But I want to show both store's login links such that if a customer is logged in any store it would show logout link only for that store.

Right now it shows logout link for both stores, even if a customer is logged in any store.

Can anyone guide on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> System->Configuration->Customers->Customer configuration->Account sharing option

Then change `Share Customer Accounts`  to `per website` from `global`

Comment: Yes I saw it already from google-search, but is there no way the session check storewise can be done from code, i.e. by overriding the `isLoggedIn` method, how to achieve this by code, what should I do so that `storeId` is taken into acount while checking `isLoggedIn`, is my question I think.

Comment: By default, Magento only supports limiting user accounts on a Global or per Website basis, not per Store.

To try to answer your question, you can force the user to logout between stores/websites. Look in Admin > System > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings and set Use SID on Frontend to No.

If the limitations have to be per Store, then you will need a module to introduce that.

Comment: Moreover account sharing setting also done as you suggested, but still same issue.